How To Unit Test Receiver Function That Uses Another Receiver Function
Let's say you have the following
type Person interface {
  GetFullName() string
  PrintName()
}
type Banker struct {
  FirstName string
  LastName string
}
func (b Banker) GetFullName() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", b.FirstName, b.LastName)
}
func (b Banker) PrintName() {
  return log.Println(b.GetFullName())
}

How do you mock GetFullName from PrintName?
Note, this is just an example to make the underlying problem (mocking receiver function used in a receiver function) easier to understand

If you want to test a method that calls other methods, one way to do is to setup the struct so that the methods that the method under test depends on returns controlled values. You cannot "override" methods to mock them.

You do not mock that stuff.

The title is just really wrong. You are not asking how to unit test a receiver function which calls another receiver function, you are asking how to mock out a receiver function. There is absolutely no direct relation between the ability to test something and mocking something, mocking should be avoided as much as possible.

Leaving aside the question of whether you should do this, one way that you could is to make the receiver function you wish to mock a wrapper around a  function variable which can be replaced in tests:
var bankerGetFullName = func(Banker) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", b.FirstName, b.LastName)
}

type Person interface {
  GetFullName() string
  PrintName()
}

type Banker struct {
  FirstName string
  LastName string
}

func (b Banker) GetFullName() string {
  return bankerGetFullName(b)
}

func (b Banker) PrintName() {
  return log.Println(b.GetFullName())
}

The function wrapper is not exported, so it cannot be mutated by code outside the package.
Then, assuming that your tests are in the same package as the code under test (which some would argue is itself undesirable), your test can replace the wrapper implementation to provide a mock as required:
   // ARRANGE
   og := bankerGetFullName
   defer func() { bankerGetFullName = og }() 
   bankerGetFullName = func(Banker) string { return "mock result" }

   sut := Banker{}

   // ACT
   result := sut.Print()

   // ASSERT
   ... test the log output to verify that "mock result" was printed ...

Caveat Developor
As I say, this is not a recommendation that you should do this, only a direct answer to the question as to how it might or could be done.

You're misunderstanding unit testing. You only mock collaborators, and there are none in this example.
You want to test the behavior of a unit, which is your Banker. If you refactor PrintName to be:
func (b Banker) PrintName() {
    log.Println(b.FirstName + " " + b.LastName)
}

your program is still correct.
